# Visual Studio 2010 settings

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am trying to compile a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010.
It contains many C++ files and it also has a couple of C files.

Because it is a C++ project and the warning level is set to /W4 I am getting a lot of warnings on the C source code.

Is there a way to select the C compiler for C source code and the C++ compiler for C++ source code?

Comment: It already does this automatically, a .c source file is compiled with the C compiler.  Without you documenting the warnings (tsk tsk), you probably want to change the /W4 option to /W3 for just the .c files.  Right-click them, Properties and change the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the file extension will be used to hint a default compilation mode. If for some reason the compilation mode was overriden, you can set it manually:
Go to properties of your C file. Inside: Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Advanced --> Compile As --> Compile as C code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you name your files with the correct extensions.

`.c` files are compiled with the C compiler.

`.cpp` files are compiled with the C++ compiler.

There's no template for a C file, just choose C++ file and name it appropriately.  Otherwise if it is already added to your project, you can still rename the file.